# parsing string into different kind of number string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsnumberformatter

I have a string called realEstateWorth with a value of $12,000,000.
I need this same string to remain a string but for any number (such as the one above) to be displayed as $12 MILLION or $6 MILLION. The point is it needs the words "MILLION" to come after the number.

I know there is nsNumberFormatter that can convert strings into numbers and vice versa but can it do what I need?

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as I see it, you have two problems:

1. You have a string representation of something that's actually a number
2. You (potentially) have a number that you want formatted as a string

So, problem #1:

To convert a string into a number, you use an `NSNumberFormatter`.  You've got a pretty simple case:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSNumber *n = [f numberFromString:@"$12,000,000"];
// n is 12000000
```

That was easy!  Now problem #2:

This is trickier, because you want a mixed spell-out style.  You could consider using an `NSNumberFormatter` again, but it's not quite right:

```
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
NSString *s = [f stringFromNumber:n];
// s is "twelve million"
```

So, we're closer.  At this point, you could perhaps maybe do something like:

```
NSInteger numberOfMillions = [n integerValue] / 1000000;
if (numberOfMillions > 0) {
  NSNumber *millions = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:numberOfMillions];
  NSString *numberOfMillionsString = [f stringFromNumber:millions]; // "twelve"

  [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
  NSString *formattedMillions = [f stringFromNumber:millions]; // "$12.00"

  if ([s hasPrefix:numberOfMillionsString]) {
    // replace "twelve" with "$12.00"
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [numberOfMillionsString length]) withString:formattedMillions];

    // if this all works, s should be "$12.00 million"
    // you can use the -setMaximumFractionDigits: method on NSNumberFormatter to fiddle with the ".00" bit
  }
}
```

## However

I don't know how well this would work in anything other than english.  **CAVEAT IMPLEMENTOR**

Comment: +1  Great explanation, especially liked you mentioned string localization / internationalization.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case scenario, you could implement a `category` on `NSString` to implement the behaviour you want.
In the method that you would do in that `category` you could take an NSNumberFormatter to bring that string to a number and by doing some modulo operation you could define if you need the word Million, or Billion, etc. and put back a string with the modulo for Million or other   way you need it to be.

That way you could just call that method on your NSString like this :

```
NSString *humanReadable = [realEstateWorth myCustomMethodFromMyCategory];
```

And also.
`NSString are immutable`, so you can't change it unless you assign a new one to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend storing this value as an NSNumber or a float.  Then you could have a method to generate an NSString to display it like:

```
- (NSString*)numberToCurrencyString:(float)num
{
   NSString *postfix = @"";
   if (num > 1000000000)
   {
      num = num / 1000000000;
      postfix = @" Billion";
   }
   else if (num > 1000000)
   {
      num = num / 1000000;
      postfix = @" Million";
   }

   NSString *currencyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%@", num, postfix];
   return currencyString;
}
```

**Note:**  Your question states that your input needs to remain a string.  That's fine.  So you'd need to 1.) first parse the number out of the string and 2.) then reconvert it to a string from a number.  I've shown how to do step 2 of this process.